# how to get multiple values returned into table? without returning a table [lua]

Tags: lua

**example**

```
function func1()
 return 1,1,1,1
end

table = {}
table = func1()

print(table)
```

I don't want to do

```
 function func1()
  return {1,1,1,1}
 end
```

because the function im working with is already defined and I cannot modify it.

**the desired output is**

1 1 1 1

but this is not the case; it only returns the first value that the function returned.

How can I make this possible? Sorry for the bad formatting; this is my first time asking a question.

Also, I'm pretty sure the table is equal to an array? so sorry for that as well.

EDIT I don't know the number of arguments either.

Answer (score 8):

A function that returns multiple results will return them separately, not as a table.

> Lua resource on multiple results: https://www.lua.org/pil/5.1.html

You can do what you want like this:

```
t = {func1()} -- wrapping the output of the function into a table
print(t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4])
```

This method is will always get all of the output values.

---

This method can also be done using `table.pack`:

```
t = table.pack(func1())
print(t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4])
```

by using `table.pack` you can discard nil results. This is can be helpful to preserve a simple check of the number of results using the length operator `#`; however it comes at the cost of no longer preserving the result "order".

To explain further, if `func1` instead returned `1, nil, 1, 1` with the first method you receive a table where `t[2] == nil`. with the `table.pack` variation you will get `t[2] == 1`.

---

Alternatively you can do this:

```
function func1()
 return 1,1,1,1
end

t = {}
t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4] = func1() -- assigning each output of the function to a variable individually 

print(t[1], t[2], t[3], t[4])
```

This method can allow you to pick and choose where outputs go or if you want to ignore one you can simply do:

```
 t[1], _, t[3], t[4] = func1() -- skip the second value
```

Comment: I recommend `t = table.pack(func1())` instead of `t = {func1()}` because then you can query the number of elements in the table with `t.n` (`#t` won't work if there are “holes”).

Comment: @HenriMenke added the `table.pack` variation to the answer, I still feel it can be a confusing result if you do expect internal `nil` values. in what i added to my answer, `table.pack` does not persevere the result. if the second result is `nil` then with `table.pack` the table you get has a `t[2]` that is not `nil` but is instead the value of result 3, and now `t[3]` is the value of result 4. if more then 1 result can return `nil`, `table.pack` makes it impossible to interpret the result